# Using MS SQL with Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I was reading Magento 1.6 RDBMS guide and it said that adapters for Oracle and MS SQL will be introduced later. Now in 1.9 under release notes, I can't find that they have added this feature. Can you please tell me if the adapters have been introduced or point me to the right documents?
Thank you

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the built in API to communicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for MS SQL and there is not support anticipated for Magento 1.x (Please read my edit below after contacting Magento support before deleting this question.)

**EDIT:** I went one step further and contacted Magento Enterprise Support to get documentation on MS SQL. Here is their response.

> I have spoken with developers on this and at this time Magento doesn't
>   support MS SQL. While future version may, currently I do not have
>   access to that information as of yet.
>
> However we are always looking at new technology and may incorporate
>   this into a future release of Magento.
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused you and look
>   forward to supporting you with any future issues you may have
>
> Regards, Warren

Comment: Thank you for your response. But according to this document there is:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/RDBMS_Guide2.pdf

Comment: and this part in section 2.2
2.2. Adapters
MySQL adapters in Magento 1.6 grew larger and became capable of abstracting
more. Additional full-functioning Oracle and Microsoft SQL Server adapters were
developed for Magento (only the MySQL adapter is included in Magento 1.6
(more adapters will be introduced later).

Comment: I have not heard of anyone using MS SQL. Why is your requirement hinging on this?

Comment: You can use MS SQL, and it has been done before. However, don't expect Magento to support it (even if they said before they would), and be prepared for problems in the future if/when they change adapters or abstraction layers.

Comment: Thank you for your response. We are hosting the website with SQL Server and the warehouse portal has to constantly communicate with the DB.  Hence, the hinging.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the API? The API doesn't care what the platform is

Answer (score 2):

Yes, MSSQL and Oracle adapters are available from Enterprise support. Not widely implemented from what I understand.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So there is no way to use the adapters for the community edition?

Comment: That is interesting, what version of EE supports this?

Comment: As I think Ben is correct that is "Fundamentally" will support MS SQL, I don't think there is anyone at Magento that is willing to support it.

Comment: I contact Magento Support to get the adaptors and they said they do not support MS SQL and will not for version 1.x

Comment: @benmarks is mssql adapters available in Magento EE support.can i use magento with mssql

Comment: @PradeepSanku nope.