# Add connection to MS SQL database

Tags: magento-1.9, database, mssql

I want to add a connection to our ERP database that uses MS-Server, but i can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I know how to connect to another MySQL DB, but for MSSQL?

**config.xml**

```
<resources>
    <erp_db>
        <connection>
            <host><![CDATA[1.2.3.4\somename]]></host>
            <username><![CDATA[user]></username>
            <password><![CDATA[password]]></password>
            <dbname><![CDATA[db_name]]></dbname>
            <!-- ??? -->
            <model>mssql</model>
            <type>pdo_mssql</type>
            <!-- ??? -->
            <active>1</active>
        </connection>
    </erp_db>
    <erp_write>
        <connection>
            <use>erp_db</use>
        </connection>
    </erp_write>
    <erp_read>
        <connection>
            <use>erp_db</use>
        </connection>
    </erp_read>
    <erp_setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
    </erp_setup>
</resources>
```

If I try this to list all tables ...

```
$resource   = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$connection = $resource->getConnection('erp_db');
$results    = $connection->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype="U"');
var_dump($results);
```

I get ...

> Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php on line 225

I also read [Using MS SQL with Magento 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68125/using-ms-sql-with-magento-1-9), some say it's not supported, but from comments it seems to be possible ...

The PDO adapter exists in `Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mssql`, but how to correctly use it?

Comment: Please check this link here it explains how to connect MsSql from magento. https://www.webinse.com/blog/connect-from-magento-to-microsoft-sql-server-on-ubuntu/

Comment: You can use MS-TDS see below
http://www.informaticapressapochista.com/linux/connect-php-code-ms-sql-server-freetds/

Comment: alternate you can use default PHP database connection to database

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to the local.xml file inside the `config/global` tag

```
<resource><!-- singular form. No 's' at the end -->
    <connection>
        <types>
            <pdo_mssql>
                <adapter>Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mssql</adapter>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Type_Db_Pdo_Mssql</class>
                <compatibleMode>1</compatibleMode><!-- Not sure of what this does or if it's even needed -->
            </pdo_mysql>
        </types>
    </connection>
</resource>
```

Still it won't work probably because the class listed above in the `class` tag does not exist...
you can create one based on `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Type_Db_Pdo_Mysql` and replace the value above with the class name you create.
What you need to change is the result of the method `_getDbAdapterClassName`.

[EDIT]
You are getting that error because the method `getResourceTypeConfig` in the same class returns null. This method should return `this->_xml->global->resource->connection->types->{$type}`. That's why I added the node `pdo_mssql` inside connection types.
[/EDIT]

Note: This is not tested, I started from the error message you got and checked what could be missing.

Comment: Had no time to test it, just checked the classes/methods you've mentioned ... so what should be the return value of `_getDbAdapterClassName`? However, thank for your time :)

Comment: Not sure. Probably the value of `adapter` from the xml. `Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mssql`. Not sure how this works.

Comment: great that you created new Html  tagname : `<Edit>` , i will start using this in our project :)

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Marius. Still no time to test :( I'll come back as soon as i have time for.